# Accessing a static HashMap outside mapper/reducer classes in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I’m trying to write a mapreduce program where the map function adds items to a HashMap, and the reducer then accesses those items and writes it to output.

```
public class MyClass {
    static HashMap<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
            temp.put("1", 1);
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce1 extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) {
            Iterator it = temp.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair = (Map.Entry<String, Integer>)it.next();
                String key = pair.getKey();
                String val = Integer.toString(pair.getValue());
                context.write(new Text(key), new Text(val));
            }
        }
    }
```

This compiles fine, but the output from the reducer is empty. I'm not great at Java, so i'm not quite sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: I'd suggest you start by going through the Word Count example (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html), and understanding what MapReduce does. Reducers and Mappers run independently and have no shared state (at least in this sense).

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding that MapReduce is a distributed algorithm running amongst many processes and potentially machines.

Each new `MyClass` instance created during that process will be empty, and not shared as part of the application lifecycle

Plus, your mapper is doing nothing. The way to send data to the reducer is to use `context.write`.

Refer to the official Hadoop documentation for wordcount code.

Comment: For the record, no one I know actually writes mapreduce. Mostly everyone doing something similar uses Spark or Flink

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks for answering! 

And believe me when I say I wouldn't use MapReduce if I had a choice, lol

Comment: Even if the state was shared, what you'd end up with by default is calling `temp.put` for every single line of your input file

Comment: If you simply want to count things, there are Counter objects that you can attach to the Context